# How would you use rationale in a sentence?

Tags: vocabulary, british-english

How is *rationale* used in a sentence? Can it be used in place of *logic?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The rationale behind all this is...

I would think that *rationale* could rather be replaced by *reasoning* than *logic*, but both are certainly possible. *Rationale* highlights more the deduction process than the set of rules behind it.

*Rationale* is derived from Latin *ratio*, which is the human reason, brain, wit, understanding.

Look at *rational*, *rationality*: in philosophy, *rationality* is the exercise of reason, a key method used to analyze the data gained through systematically conducted observations ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationality)). In economics and such, a *rational decision* is one that is optimal given the available information.

Therefore, a sentence using *rationale* would list the information and reasoning that led to a decision.

Answer (score 4):

Rationale can sometimes be used in place of reason or logic. (It is not a drop-in replacement that would work in all cases)

Examples from the [American Corpus:](http://www.americancorpus.org/)

> The rationale the President gave for going in to Afghanistan was to keep a weak state from turning into another al Qaeda haven.
>
> The rationale is she wants to be president.
>
> His rationale is the equivalent to stating that our AP European history classes in the state of Arizona.

Comment: Can I use "Rationale for PhD Research" as a section title?